# Query parameter not accepted by Google Analytics because it includes dash(-)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I googled a lot but could not find a solution yet.

Here is how my in-site search url looks like: https://www.magidostur.com/search-tours/?tour-search=mysearchterm&tax-tour-destinations=&month=

tour-search is my query parameter, and mysearchterm is my search term, obviously.

Here as you can see when i try to add my search term on advanced settings, analytics does not accept my parameter and it says "please only separate parameters with comma."

What should i do?

Thank you.

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhxd9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the 'view_search_resutls' event manually, if you are using GTM.
Just disable enhanced measurement for site search and implement the event via GTM.

Comment: Is it possible to point me to an article on how to do it?

Comment: It is actually super easy:
In GTM you create a new GA4 event with the event name "view_search_results".
In this event, you add the parameter "search_query" with your search query parameter as value.
The last thing you need to do is add a trigger, that fires only on search result pages.

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/track-site-search-with-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics/

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Now i can see view_search_results on analytics. But I cant see the search terms still.

I configured my tag and trigger as such: https://imgur.com/a/LkgXDDB

And i created a custom dimension on analytics. But i still cant see the search terms: https://imgur.com/a/fiSBTVT

I would be so grateful if you can take a look one last time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The custom parameter in GA4 has to be "search_query" as it is configured in GTM, not "search_term"